# Creating a new column by summing previous ones with pandas error

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a picture of my file, the upper one is the original, the bottom one is what I get after I run my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGwEe.jpg

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\RGB.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df['RGB'] = df.iloc[1:7:,:5:8].sum(axis=1)
df.to_excel(path)
```

Basically what I want to do is to create a new column called RGB, and sum the values of red, blue and green columns, hence I did the 1:7:,:5:8, to apply it to all of the rows, and the 5.,6. and 7. (red,blue,green) columns, but instead it just made RGB equal to the black(first) column...

Not sure what did I do wrong here.

My original dataframe:

```
  Black  Orange  Yellow  Brown  Blue   Green  Red
      7       4       3      1      6      7    2
      3       3       3      8      4      5    2
      6       7       3      2      2      2    5
      2       9       2      2      2      2    2
      5       5       5      5      5      5    5
      2       2       8      2     27      8    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra semicolons in your code, at `df.iloc[1:7:,:5:8]`. Try without them. let me know if it works, otherwise i will come back with a more general solution.

```
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\RGB.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df['RGB'] = df.iloc[1:7,5:8].sum(axis=1)
df.to_excel(path)
```

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks a lot! I thought the syntax for df.iloc is [:,:] my bad

Comment: It is, but with one semicolon only. Don't forget to upvote/accept supporting answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You shoud be able to do it like this.

```
df['RGB'] = df['Red'] + df['Green'] + df['Blue']
```

Comment: Thank you! I will need to do this for different parts of the code